# How to multi-thread Open Dynamics Engine( ODE)

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, tbb

I have been trying to parallelize ODE (Open Dynamics Engine) via TBB, meaning each thread having its own ODE environment. But it didn't work, I guess there is a variable that is being shared by TBB threads. Has anyone ever able to parallelize ODE using threads (pthreads or TBB threads)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generically, you may want to look through the source code of ODE for variables declared at namespace or global scope, or variables declared as `static` in global, namespace, class, or function scopes. Mark them all as thread private, using syntax suitable to the compiler you're using - `__thread` is commonly supported (at least by GCC, Clang, and ICC), but is not standardized. In C++11, you can use `thread_local` (or, in C11, `_Thread_local`).

Comment: Thanks! someone made ODE multi-threaded with TBB (https://github.com/sgvandijk/ode-tbb). I used this package and it worked.